# clang tidy pro type member init resharper

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I've got some code parsing json like so:

```
  QJsonParseError errors;
  auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(myJson.toUtf8(), &errors);
```

Resharper's clang tidy suggestions flags that QJsonParseError errors is an 'uninitialized record type'

The suggested fix is to zero initialize the variable via {} for C++11.
The autofix offered by resharper, puts in some brackets like: QJsonParseError errors{};

What does that actually mean/do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero initialization guarantees that the members of a class/struct are zero initialized. For example -

```
struct student
{
    int idNo;
    char name[20];
};
```

So, if object of `student` is zero-initialized, then it is guaranteed that the member variables `idNo, name` value(s) are initialized with zeroes (i.e., `idNo` = 0 and `name` array filled with zeroes).

In your case, `QJsonParseError` members are zero initialized rather than filling with some random values during object initialization.